# How to reorder a existing wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress

Google gives priority to the first link in the HTML code and not where it appears on the page.

i want to know how to
Reorder the code of my existing wordpress template so that the search engine reads: Header / Content / Navigation Menu / Footer.
basically i want a guideline on how to do this.little help and i think i can figure out this on my own.thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use a plugin that sets a wordpress snippet to a meta description in your template.

This plugin will let you set the post excerpt in the meta description- http://guff.szub.net/2005/09/01/head-meta-description/